# ember CollectionView set a className on last highlighted

Tags: ember.js, collectionview

I have a list of items that I display using an **Ember.CollectionView** with a tagName of **ul**.
I would like to set a specific **className** to an element in the li that gets ***mouseOvered*** but only one one element can have the class at any given time, basically on mouseOver of any elements I need to remove the class from all elements and add it to the specific one currently over.

```
App.AnimalsListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  contentBinding: 'parentView.controller.content',
  classNames: ['animals'],
  elementId: 'animalsList',
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    highlightNameBinding: "",
    classNameBindings: ['animal', 'highlightName'],
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(
      '{{view.content.title}}'
    ),
    mouseEnter: function() {
      // need to remove highlighted class on all elements
      // this.set('highlightName', 'highlighted'); on current element
    },
    mouseLeave: function() {

    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to keep the selected item would be by adding a selection property to your *Animal* model. You can then add a method in controller to iterated though your list of `animals` and reset them all to false

```
clearHighlighted: function() { 
  animals.forEach(function(animal, index, self) {
    animal.set('highlighted', false);
  });
}
```

On mouse enter then you would first call that method to reset all highlighted properties to `false`, and then set the `highlighted` property for current view to `true`. Not the most efficient, but I think in addition to what Unspecified provides above this would be relatively easy to implement.

Comment: That's a good enough idea! Is this the correct syntax?  In my controller i defined  clearHighlighted: function() { this.get('content').every(function(item, index,self){ item.set('highlighted', false); }}  but for some reason it seems to only iterate first item then exit I tried to put a console log in there and it just loops once although I have 10 items in content...

Comment: I think I got it, it seems to work if I return true; within the every function, is that the right way?

Comment: you are right, looks like the every method stops iteration as soon if the callback function returns false. It would be much better to use `forEach` in this case. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Unspecified I should read the API more carefully. using `setEach` would be more elegant here.

Answer (score 4):

You could use className Bindings by toggling a boolean value when the mouse enters or leaves...

```
App.AnimalsListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  contentBinding: 'parentView.controller.content',
  classNames: ['animals'],
  elementId: 'animalsList',
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    isHighlighted: false,
    //highlight-name is the CSS Class to be applied when isHighlighted = true
    classNameBindings: ['animal', 'isHighlighted:highlight-name'],
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(
      '{{view.content.title}}'
    ),
    mouseEnter: function() {
      //due to the following line, class will be applied when mouse enters
      this.set('isHighlighted', true);
      //this.toggleProperty('isHighlighted'); if using the latest ember
    },
    mouseLeave: function() {
      //remove the class by making the value false when mouse leaves
      this.set('isHighlighted', false);
      //this.toggleProperty('isHighlighted'); if using the latest ember
    }
  })
});
```

Hope this helps...

**Update on highlighting an item on click**

This method is particularly useful if you are planning on routing on clicking item in a list, and doesn't require clearing the boolean flag by iterating over...

```
//define a reusable component this way

App.ListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        classNameBindings: ["isSelected:highlight-item"],
        isSelected: (->
            return this.get('content.id') === this.get('parentView.selected');
        ).property('parentView.selected')
    })
})

App.PostsController =  Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [{
            name: "name1",
            id: 1,
            property1: "etc"
        },
        {
            name: "name2",
            id: 2,
            property1: "etc"                    
        }
        ]
})

//App.PostsView Handlebars
{{#collection App.ListView contentBinding="content" selectedBinding="controllers.postController.content.id"}}
    Name: {{view.content.name}}<br>
    Comments: {{view.content.property1}}
{{/collection}}
{{outlet}} //to connect App.PostView

//Now when an item is clicked you could send the context object or just the context id
```

If you are not using routing you could go with what said by Aras

Comment: Thanks a lot that helps but I'm still missing a piece of this, because on mouse out I only want for it to set highlight to false IF another element is highlighted otherwise if you mouse out on another section of the page it should stay highlighted

Comment: I answered on how to highlight on hover, let me update on how to highlight when an item is clicked...